# DataTable not refreshing when using Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I already check every single question related to this, and nothing seems to works. Here is my case:

Im using 1.10.20 DataTable Version, and Im trying to refresh the Data after an Insert/Delete in the Serverside using Ajax jquery($.ajax), then Im trying to refresh the Datatable obj with no luck.

My Code:

```
    function displaymensajes()
{   

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: 'ajaxscripts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({ "WTDo" : 'displaymensajes', "userid" : <?php echo $_SESSION["IDInversionista"] ?>}) ,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (response) {
    $('#tbodymensajes').html(response);



//If I make the call here($("#mensajesTable").DataTable();) instead of on document ready, the Second time the functions is called(I have to call it again when I insert or delete records) I get the error when it can't initialize twice and stuff.
//I try do the ajax.reload() no luck, its gives me the error where Json is not properly formatted(of course I not using Json format in the server side, the response is pure HTML code)
//I try delete the table and create it again, no luck

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
}); 

}

displaymensajes();


//On Document ready... Initialize the API
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#mensajesTable").DataTable(); 
 } );
```

Results:

There is 2 rows in the Table but Datatable still thinks there is only one. Only catches up when I refresh the page. HELP?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/755c6.png)

PD: Can someone make an refresh() or update() to this API Please?

Comment: The issue is that you're replacing the tbody and not the whole table - can you return the whole table instead (if you don't want to use .destroy)

Comment: I can try that and see how it goes

Comment: YESS!!!!! YESSS!!!!!!....Omg...it works, Thanks!!!.. No in a million years I would think about that!!! Appreciate your Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

After making your ajax call, you need to use the response of the ajax call to replace the HTML of the table with the updated HTML. 
It's hard to say how you would do this without seeing more of your code, but a common method is to return the table content from the server side code as HTML and replace the updated content. To do this, you would add something like this to your ajax call:

```
$.ajax(...<your current code>).done(function(response){
    $("#yourTableId").html(response)
});
```

For this to work, your server side code needs to be returning the updated HTML (or JSP or whatever you are using) as a response to the ajax call.

Comment: So instead of using  success: function (response), I should use .done, got it, now where I should put the datatable code to do a refresh after I inner the response?

Comment: `.done` / `success:` do the same thing here - you can use either if you're including it inline

Comment: Ok, I used done like this: `$.ajax(..my code..).done(function(response){$('#tbodymensajes').html(response);
 $("#mensajesTable").DataTable();});` and the Jquery inner works great, but the datatable still doesn't refresh... After I successfully insert a record using the another ajax function I call displaymensajes(), and I have more rows in the table than then number listed by datatable

Comment: Funny thing is, after I used Done instead the Success, im not getting the "can't initialize twice" error from datatable. Still doesn't work but, progress is progress lol

Comment: Can you add your server side code? You want to make sure the response it's sending has the data after it is updated. The server side code that fires when it receives the ajax call should update the database, pull the new values from the database, and then return a generated HTML with the updated data as a response.

Comment: there is a lot of server side PHP and mysql in the ajaxscripts.php...the return is basically: `echo "<tr class='tr-shadow'> <td>".$row["fechahora"]."</td> <td>".$row["mensaje"]."</td><td>".$Fromuser."</td><td>".$row["Touser"]."</td><td>".$received."</td><td><div align='center'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt' style='cursor: pointer;' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal' onclick='document.getElementById(".$obj.").value=".'"'.$row["ID"].'"'."'></i></div></td></tr>"`... There is indeed data in the response cause Ajax is embedding the html code successfully.

Comment: I did try destroy() like this: `var table = $('#mensajesTable').DataTable();  
        table.destroy();
        $('#mensajesTable').empty(); // empty in case the columns change 
        table = $('#mensajesTable').DataTable();`.. This code works even worst, it makes ajax stop working, only works when the page refresh.

Comment: If you see in the PHP echo...Im only innering the TBody of the table...The columns are static in the DOM. dont know if this is important or not

Comment: The destroy code gives me this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined